# RxJava Observable get notified on first emission

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have three Observables which I combine with combineLastest:

```
    Observable<String> o1 = Observable.just("1");
    Observable<String> o2 = Observable.just("2");
    Observable<String> o3 = Observable.just("3");

    Observable.combineLatest(o1, o2, o3, new Func3<String, String, String, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(String s, String s2, String s3) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

I want to be notified about the first emission of one of the Observables without ignoring the later emissions, which I guess [first operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html) would do. Is there a convenient operator for that like (example):

```
    o1.doOnFirst(new Func1<String, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(String s) {
            return null;
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can have a practical `doOnFirst` with a simple [`take`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html) if you're handling a stream:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> withDoOnFirst(Observable<T> source, Action1<T> action) {
    return source.take(1).doOnNext(action).concatWith(source);
}
```

This way the action is only bound to the first item.

This could be changed to handle observables which are **not** backed by streams adding [`skip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skip.html) to skip the already taken items:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> withDoOnFirstNonStream(Observable<T> source, Action1<T> action) {
    return source.take(1).doOnNext(action).concatWith(source.skip(1));
}
```

Comment: Requiring two subscriptions to source is potentially inefficient (we don't know what overhead that could involve for any particular observable). I'd suggest going with an answer that used one subscription for general use. For a hot source you could miss emissions too.

Answer (score 7):

For convenience, I created these extension functions for `Flowable` and `Observable`.
Note, that with `doOnFirst()` the action will be called before the first element emission, whilst `doAfterFirst()` will firstly emit the first item and then perform the action.

```
fun <T> Observable<T>.doOnFirst(onFirstAction: (T) -> Unit): Observable<T> =
    take(1)
        .doOnNext { onFirstAction.invoke(it) }
        .concatWith(skip(1))

fun <T> Flowable<T>.doOnFirst(onFirstAction: (T) -> Unit): Flowable<T> =
    take(1)
        .doOnNext { onFirstAction.invoke(it) }
        .concatWith(skip(1))

fun <T> Observable<T>.doAfterFirst(afterFirstAction: (T) -> Unit): Observable<T> =
    take(1)
        .doAfterNext { afterFirstAction.invoke(it) }
        .concatWith(skip(1))

fun <T> Flowable<T>.doAfterFirst(afterFirstAction: (T) -> Unit): Flowable<T> =
    take(1)
        .doAfterNext { afterFirstAction.invoke(it) }
        .concatWith(skip(1))
```

Usage is as simple as this:

```
Flowable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
            .doOnFirst { System.err.println("First $it") }
            .subscribe { println(it) }
```

Output:

```
// First 1  
// 1  
// 2  
// 3
```

And:

```
Flowable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
            .doAfterFirst { System.err.println("First $it") }
            .subscribe { println(it) }
```

Output:

```
// 1  
// First 1
// 2  
// 3
```

Comment: Be careful with "skip(1)" with Subjects. Then after first emited value stream is terminated.
You can use "this"

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of solutions I can think of.
The first one is an ugly but simple hack of doOnNext. Just add a boolean field to the `Action1` indicating whether the first item has been received. Once received, do whatever it is you want to do, and flip the boolean. For example:

```
Observable.just("1").doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {

        boolean first = true;

        @Override
        public void call(String t) {
            if (first) {
                // Do soemthing
                first = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

The second one is to subscribe twice on the observable you want to monitor using `publish` or `share()`, with one of those publications going through `first` (depending on whether you want to manually connect to the published observable). You'll end up with two separate observables that emit the same items, only the first one will stop after the first emission:

```
ConnectableObservable<String> o1 = Observable.just("1").publish();

o1.first().subscribe(System.out::println); //Subscirbed only to the first item
o1.subscribe(System.out::println); //Subscirbed to all items

o1.connect(); //Connect both subscribers
```

Comment: Your first suggestion will only work once. Better to wrap with defer to hold the boolean state so you get the behaviour on each subscription.

Answer (score 4):

Using [rxjava-extras](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras):

```
observable
  .compose(Transformers.doOnFirst(System.out::println))
```

It's unit tested and under the covers just uses a per-subscription counter in an operator. Note that per-subscription is important as there are plenty of uses cases where an observable instance gets used more than once and we want the `doOnFirst` operator to apply each time.

Source code is [here](https://github.com/davidmoten/rxjava-extras/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/davidmoten/rx/internal/operators/OperatorDoOnNth.java).

Comment: Oh snap, even more RxJava! ;) 
Thanks.

Comment: More RxGoodies! Hooray